How to flag AI content in Teams botbuilder?
According to the Microsoft Team's store validation guidelines, apps with AI-generated content need to flag which messages are AI generated.
According to the image which can ben seen here, there seems to be a way this can be flagged within the UI of Teams. "ai-generated content may be incorrect"
Using botbuilder-python, is anyone aware of how to flag this?

This is the build in functionality in M365 Copilot and If you are creating your own custom UI, you can add your custom message there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/bot-messages-ai-generated-content?tabs=before%2Cbotmessage
This is the documentation for the javascript library, however I'm also not able to find the python way

I managed to implement this, but using the Bot Framework SDK for JavaScript/TypeScript. Here's the card I send to flag AI-generated content:


{
    type: "message",
    text: "Hello world",
    entities: [
        {
            type: "https://schema.org/Message",
            "@type": "Message",
            "@context": "https://schema.org",
            additionalType: ["AIGeneratedContent"] // AI label
        }
    ]
}



For Python, the approach should be similar. You'd need to include the same metadata (entities with the AIGeneratedContent label) in the message payload. Unfortunately, I haven't implemented this in Python myself, but the concept should translate easily
